# Angular cannot find module to import on ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, module, router

app.module.ts

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
>
> import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
>
> import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
>
> import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
>
> import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
>
> import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
>
> import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
>
> import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
>
>
> import { Addproduct } from '../addproduct/addproduct'
>
>
> @NgModule({
> declarations: [AppComponent, Addproduct], entryComponents: [Addproduct], .. .. .. })
> ```

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp9rR.png)

error is this:

```
 ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(11,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../addproduct/addproduct'.

I am tried a lot of troubleshooting but still got an error. I am using updated ionic version
```

Comment: I think you have a problem with the import, from the picture I think it should be `../product/product` instead of `../addproduct/addproduct`

Comment: BTW check again where is `AddProduct`, the module or the page, and that is the end of the correction I point you

Comment: I tried to work on that but still no luck

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Product } from '../product/product';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HomePage,
  Product
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  AppComponent,
  HomePage,
  Product,
  ], 
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

Comment: I'll updated the image on top for more info. thanks

Comment: import { AddproductPage } from "../pages/addproduct/addproduct";

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is coming because you didn't specify what you are importing properly

Ex:
If you are importing a component it should be like this:

```
import { Addproduct } from '../addproduct/addproduct.component';
```

If you are importing a page then:

```
import { Addproduct } from '../addproduct/addproduct.page';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is component then

```
import { addproductComponent } from "../components/addproduct/addproduct";
```

If it is a page

```
 import { AddproductPage } from "../pages/addproduct/addproduct";
```